# history erase shell script not working

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, history

I am creating shelll script that is erase history of commands in the terminal. But the script is not erase the history of commands in the terminal. I follow below procedure 
1. My script contains following lines

```
#!/bin/bash
history -c
```

2. I changed file to be executable

```
chmod +x foo.sh
```

3. I run the script

```
./foo.sh
```

but the script is not working & not erasing my history of commands. Why?

Update:
I alternatively write a script to clear the history. still same problem occurs.
My alternative script is,

```
#!/bin/bash
# Bash Shell store history in the file ~/.bashrc
rm -r ~/.bash_history
```

This is also not clear history of commands.

Answer (score 3):

- `rm -f ~/.bash_history` (don't use `-r`!) will remove the history log, which in the default configuration of most distros is read when you start a new shell. Doing this will therefore only affect shells that you start after running this command. You can replace your current shell with another one by running `exec "$SHELL"` to avoid creating a new terminal window.
- `history -c` clears the history for the *current* shell, and does not delete `~/.bash_history`. But when you *run* a script [the current shell creates a *new* shell to run the script in and *exits* that shell when the script is done](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/060). Instead, to execute a script in the *current* shell you have to [*source*](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Sourcing) the script. In your case, try running `. foo.sh`.

Answer (score 1):

I you want to "clear our traces" after you exit the shell you might want to run these commands from your logout script, that is the `~/.bash_logout` file.

Maybe you do not want at all your history of commands to be saved, in this case you can set `HISTFILESIZE=0` (in your `~/.profile` file or in the shell you are using).

See also: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=920530